# dropwizard-giving-400-error-when-creating-new-resource using POST

Tags: java, json, rest, post, dropwizard

```
public class UserProfileData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = true)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "country", nullable = true)
    private String country;

    public UserProfileData() {
    }

    public UserProfileData(String firstName, String lastName, String country) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.country = country;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setObjectId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof UserProfileData)) return false;

        final UserProfileData that = (UserProfileData) o;

        return Objects.equals(this.id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equals(this.firstName, that.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(this.lastName, that.lastName) &&
                Objects.equals(this.country, that.country);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName, country);
    }
}

========================================================================

DAO Method

   public UserProfileData create(UserProfileData userProfileData) {
        LOGGER.info("UserProfileData: Persisting New User");
        return persist(userProfileData);        
    }

=======================================================================

Resource Call
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserProfileDataResource {

 @POST
    @Path("/create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @UnitOfWork
    public UserProfileData createUser(UserProfileData userProfileData) {
        //ResourceHelper.checkRequiredParams(requesterId);
        LOGGER.info("User created");
        return userProfileDataDAO.create(userProfileData);
    }
======================================================================
```

when i call the resource using to create a new User Data, it gives me error

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d
>   "{"firstName":"Sachin","lastName":"Tendulkar","country":"India"}"
>   http://localhost:8080/user/create
>
> Error: {"code":400,"message":"Unable to process JSON","details":null}

Tried with almost everything but not able to figure out why this error is coming and how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 6):

To get helpful message regarding 400 error, register this on jersey:

```
environment.jersey().register(new JsonProcessingExceptionMapper(true));
```

It will give more detailed message on 400 response.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons why you get this error. Try putting the logging level to debug in the config file, i.e. :

```
logging:
    level: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

Your curl request is encapsulating the JSON data with quotes ("") which breaks because of the quotes in JSON. So what you sent to the server is actually "{".

Use apostrophe (') instead:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"firstName":"Sachin","lastName":"Tendulkar","country":"India"}' http://localhost:8080/user/create
```

Comment: I tried with (') but still getting the same error
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"firstName":"Sachin","lastName":"Tendulkar","country":"India"}' http://localhost:8080/user/create

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with another type of post data, using `raw` (with JSON-format string) instead of `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Follow that example, I used Postman client & raw post data and it worked!
[image]